# Versioning: consistency between different environments such as DEV, TEST and PROD

Tags: versioning

I am trying to devise a versioning system for a product that we are building. We have three environments: DEV, TEST and PROD.

One system is that eg. if we have a (small) change in DEV, we increment the version to 5.1.2 from 5.1.1, have this version number propagate to TEST and PROD as well. Then for the next (small) change in say TEST, it would be 5.1.3 and the same propagated to DEV and PROD as well.

Is this a good idea? I do not find it to be so. But haven't been able to think of or find anything better.

Is there a general guidance about this? Any suggestions? Or am I doing this completely wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you making the change in TEST and then copying to DEV?

Answer (score 2):

In an ideal world you deploy the same code (*exactly* the same) to every environment in turn - in the case of compiled code this should be the same compiled/packaged binary.

In terms of deployment the (compiled) code should more or less always follow a path from dev -> test -> live (this is a sweeping generalisation and there's a whole load of context dependent stuff that will invalidate it).

If you look at "Semantic Versioning" you'll have good guidelines for version numbers.

Personally I'm happiest when the least significant version number (patch and below in major.minor.patch ) is set on my CI build server and the deployments are always of packages generated by the build server. I also want the git hash (or equivalent) encoded into the deployed package because then you positively, absolutely, know which version of the code you're looking at.

This doesn't completely answer the question because one would need more context (details of your specific environment)